# Can I use these wires for AC current?

Tags: voltage, ac, safety, wire, insulation

I bought [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0796HXNRX) wires on amazon, and I noticed in the description that they are rated for 80 volts, and are specifically *not* to be used for household 110v/220v wiring. However, this wire is basically all that I have on hand. The insulation is actually pretty thick (about a millimeter), and I want to use it for separated wires. Is there actually any problem with me using it for 110/220v ac current?

Comment: The manufacturer says they're not rated for anything above 80 V. Why would we know better? You have given no details of the application. I didn't check the link but being an Amazon purchase I suspect that it will be impossible to get a datasheet for the product. "No datasheet? No sale!"

Comment: Given the safety margin of the insulation is 50% (a lot), it meant they fail at 120V. 110VAC peaks at 170V, 230VAC peaks at 350V. So … no. You can't use those wires.

Comment: Why isn't there a dedicated "Answer in the comment section" flag anymore... Apparently it's still necessary.

Comment: @Janka, how do you know that the safety margin of the insulation is 50%? It's 1mm thick silicone, aught that be enough to insulate much higher voltage?

Comment: the product page clearly states: IMPORTANT: DO NOT use for building/household 110/220 V ac wiring. Why is this even a question.  Voting to close

Comment: @Rafael, i downvoted your question because you are asking a question when you already know the answer, or worse, you may be seeking someone's help with getting yourself a Darwin Award

Comment: @Rafael *"It's 1mm thick silicone, aught that be enough to insulate much higher voltage?"* You're kidding right? How many times have you touched 120/220VAC to know whether it is enough insulation or not? What measurements and reliability tests have you done? And you question the labels put on by people who made it and instead want to use your gut feel for something you have no experience with?

Comment: The supplier's warning gives a VERY STRONG indication that using it for mains use is a bad idea. I would expect that 110 VAC it would be 'probably safe' if used in a location where there was no hazard to people or equipment or buildings etc BUT there is no certainty.| Your insurance would not be valid if you used this for mains AC.| The code they give (26121500) just means "wire". | Q1: What is your application? Q2: What current do you wish to carry?. || You can buy flexible leads rated at 10A or maybe 20A in any store selling electrical products or home goods.

Comment: ... (Walmart et al). This is NOT intended for fixed use but is 100 VAC rated.

Comment: Technically, you CAN use them for AC - as long as it's low voltage AC, < 50V RMS to stay within the 80V peak. But household AC? No way.

Comment: @Rafael: I don't know it, and if an engineer does not know it, he makes a hilarious guess on the safe side. That would be +50%. It fails even with that hilarious guess. In reality, it's sure much less than that.

Answer (score 6):

From the link provided:

> IMPORTANT: DO NOT use for building/household 110/220 V ac wiring

There is no datasheet either.

Every component has a voltage rating beyond which there can be **no reliable operation or characteristics** . They can breakdown in different ways at higher voltage.

---

### **Please do not use for safety reasons.**

Answer (score 3):

### Absolutely not, no way, no how.

Both the NEC (or your local electrical code, surely derived from NEC) and UL's White Book are very clear on what is safe for electrical work and what is not.

NEC 110.2.  **Equipment must be *approved***.  That means some authority like UL must certify it as safe.  Next paragraph, NEC 110.3(B), **Equipment must be used according to instructions and labeling**. (because the UL listing is contingent on use as-labeled.) So "Do not use on household wiring" means exactly that.

### Also, it's fine-stranded wire.  You won't like it.

110/220V mains connections are made either through backstabs (you can't use stranded wire - nor #12 - in backstabs).  Or terminal screws (that squishy fine-strand stuff will not work on a terminal screw; I put the denser-stranded THHN on terminal screws all the time, and that's fairly hard to get right.  Or wire nuts (which won't like the ultra-fine strands one bit.)  None of these play well with these kinds of fine strands.  They're looking for 29-strand at absolute most, preferably 19.

### Real electrical wire is *not* 45 cents a foot

*why the bloody green blazes would you pay $9 for 20 feet of wire?*  It doesn't matter what you're using it for; bog-standard THHN/THWN-2 wire is far cheaper than that.  Seriously unless there was a Code reason not to, I'd just use THHN for individual wires for almost any application.

Seriously, go down to the local big-box, you can get all the black, white and red pigtails you'll ever need for under $1, either by buying a couple feet of Romex and cutting it up, or buying single THHN strands in solid or stranded. Solid if you're going on screws. (and you can't use backstabs with #12).

### Besides, it's cheap Cheese junk.

Certain channels -- eBay, AliExpress, and Amazon *Marketplace* -- are flooded with cheap junk from Alibaba. This is Amazon Marketplace, which is basically eBay in sheep's clothing.  See?

[image]

Sold by XXXX and Fulfilled by Amazon     -or-
Sold by and ships from XXXX

So you can use the cheapies all you like in low voltage DC projects as the damage is likely to be pretty contained... but using it on anything that touches mains power is *out of the question*.

How is this enforced? On post-permit inspection (you *are* pulling a permit or getting a waiver, yes?) or post-accident.  The insurance company is keenly interested in those cause-of-accident reports.